# How to send a woocommerce cart details in ninja form email?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, ninja-forms

I want to send woocommerce cart details from ninja form plugin
**Is there any hook or any addon for sending a cart details to the user in email**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your custom form action and send an email with your custom content. See https://developer.ninjaforms.com/codex/custom-form-action/ for instructions.

Also, Ninja Forms provides the filter "ninja_forms_submit_data", this filter can be use to alter field values (you can populate a field with cart items). Here you can find detailed doc: https://developer.ninjaforms.com/codex/submission-processing-hooks/

Remember you can get cart content by calling `WC()->cart->get_cart_contents()` function.